# Undefinable subset of $(\mathbb{N}, <)$

Tags: model-theory

Could you help me to solve the following task:

*Find a subset* $X \subseteq \mathbb{N}$ *which is not definable in* $(\mathbb{N}, <)$.

For example, in $(\mathbb{N}, +)$, set of even number is definable by formula $\varphi(x) \equiv \exists y (x = y + y)$. Negation of this formula define set of odd numbers.

How to be sure that set of even numbers is not definable subset od $\mathbb{N}$ in $(\mathbb{N},<)$? If I suppose that the set of even numbers is definable with formula $\varphi(x)$, than $\neg \varphi(x)$ define set of odd numbers. I should make contradiction with something. I dan't know with what?

How to proove that some set is not definable in $(\mathbb{N},<)$? I don't know that procedure.

Thank you!

Comment: Can you include more details about the context of the question and your thoughts?

Comment: The question is crystal clear!  For a question whose only tag is model-theory that is more than enough.

Comment: Please, please, stop voting to close questions just because they are short (and clear).

Comment: An easy way to see that there is an undefinable subset is to use a countability argument: there are countably many sentences, but uncountably many subsets of $\mathbb{N}$. This also generalises very nicely.

Comment: @VivaanDaga +1, but the OP says *find*. Maybe a constructive (diagonalization free) answer would be more appropriate.

Comment: @PrimoPetri The way the question is formulated is in clear contradiction with the site policy. It is indeed a very clear mathematical question, but it is a "this is my homework, please solve it" question, with no indication of what the OP knows about the subject, what they have tried, why they have difficulty solving it. It is your right to disagree with the site policy, but there are appropriate places to discuss that.

Comment: @CaptainLama If I knew how to solve this, I wouldn't even ask. I apologize if I broke any rules of site policy. I just need help.

Comment: [Quick beginner guide for asking a well-received question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35391) + [please avoid "no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933).

Comment: @AnneBauval Thank you. I will pat attention in my next question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a now-deleted answer, user1047209 indicated an alternative approach, based on showing that $(\mathbb{N},<)$ is a *minimal structure*: Every definable set in one variable is finite or cofinite. Although the answer was flawed, the approach is valid. $(\mathbb{N},<)$ is indeed a minimal structure, and it follows that the set of even numbers, like any infinite and coinfinite set, fails to be definable in this structure.

For each $n>0$, let $P_n$ be a binary relation symbol. We interpret $P_n$ on $\mathbb{N}$ so that $P_n(x,y)$ holds if and only if $x < y$ and there are exactly $n-1$ elements between $x$ and $y$. Now it is a fact that the complete theory of the structure $(\mathbb{N},<,0,(P_n)_{n>0})$ eliminates quantifiers.

I will show that $(\mathbb{N},<,0,(P_n)_{n>0})$ is a minimal structure. It follows immediately that $(\mathbb{N},<)$ is also minimal.

Let's enumerate the atomic formulas with parameters and a single free variable $x$. For each, I will indicate whether it is finite or cofinite.

- $x = x$ (cofinite - all of $\mathbb{N}$)
- $x = a$ (finite - a singleton)
- $a = x$ (finite - a singleton)
- $x < x$ (finite - empty)
- $x < a$ (finite)
- $a < x$ (cofinite)
- $P_n(x,x)$ (finite - empty)
- $P_n(x,a)$ (finite - at most one element)
- $P_n(a,x)$ (finite - a singleton)

Now an arbitrary formula with parameters and one free variable $x$ is equivalent to a boolean combination of the atomic formulas above, by quantifier elimination. And a boolean combination of finite and cofinite sets is finite or cofinite. So we're done.

Note that the non-trivial part of this answer is proving quantifier elimination in the language with the relation symbols $P_n$. Similarly, the nontrivial part of Primo Petri's answer is proving that $N$ is an elementary extension of $\mathbb{N}$. To answer a question like this, you usually can't avoid doing some nontrivial work to understand the definable sets.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 4):

At the moment the answer of @user1047209 is not correct.

My answer uses a less elementary method (therefore it would be great if @user1047209 could correct their proof).

I will prove that the set of even elements is not definable.

Consider the model $N={\mathbb N} \cup \big({\mathbb Q}\times{\mathbb Z}\big)$ with the following order: the elements of ${\mathbb N}$ preceed the elements of ${\mathbb Q}\times{\mathbb Z}$. The set ${\mathbb Q}\times{\mathbb Z}$ is ordered with the lexicographic order.

$N$ is a saturated elementary extension of ${\mathbb N}$.  (This is not proved here. BTW saturation is not necessary for the argument).

Suppose for a contradiction that $\varphi(x)$ define the even number. Then ${\mathbb N}\models \forall x\ \ \varphi(x)\not\leftrightarrow\varphi(x+1)$, where $x+1$ denotes the successor of $x$. Thoughnot in the language, this is a definable function.

But $\forall x\ \ \varphi(x)\not\leftrightarrow\varphi(x+1)$ is not true in $N$. In fact, the map that is the identity on ${\mathbb N}$ and maps $\langle q,n\rangle$ to  $\langle q,n+1\rangle$ is an automorphism of $N$.

Comment: As commented twice above, this question goes against our [quality standard policy](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/enforcement-of-quality-standards). Instead of posting an answer, you should encourage the person who posted the question to improve it.